# How to get rid of windows in Vim completely?

Tags: vim

I really can't stand vertical or horizontal windows split in Vim, mainly because I never remember how to jump from one to another and all the windows-related commands.

For example, when I use the help command, Vim opens the text in a horizontal split. Is it possible to configure Vim such that **buffers** are always used instead of windows?

Comment: Is your question "how to open help not in window split?"

Comment: @Kent: In that case it would be "how to open help in a separate buffer", but the question in general is "how to open in a separate buffer anything that Vim would open by default in a window split?". Is there some setting that allows me to replace windows with buffers anywhere?

Comment: Just as a reminder, the window command prefix is `^W`, vertical resizing is done with `-/+` and arrow keys are to switch panes...

Comment: Windows are very useful, I think you should learn how to use them. Take a look at: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buffers are the in-memory text/file you opened. Window is the way that vim shows a buffer(s) to you.  You cannot see a buffer without window. I guess what you meant is, always using single maximized window.

To the question : `how to open help in a separate buffer`:

```
autocmd FileType help wincmd o
```

will do. It open help doc in a maximized window, of course, in a separated buffer.

To "disable" split, just don't execute those split commands.. like `:sp` ...

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that to me. Now the terminology is clear. But I don't understand what `o` really does. If I open one random file and then type `:help someplugin.txt` the help text is correctly opened in a full size window. But I cannot switch to the previous buffer with `:bp`. Also, if I close the help and open it again it is again in a horizontal split. Basically, to explain myself further, I'd like to open the help file as if I did `:e textfile.txt`.

Comment: @rubik give this line a try: `autocmd FileType help :autocmd BufEnter * wincmd o`

Comment: I cannot switch back and forth between the help and the other buffers but at least if I reopen it, it stays maximized. So I think it's ok!

Comment: @rubik switching between buffers is out of this topic. you can `ctrl-o/i` to jump, or using buffer navigation cmds... I suggest trying window-splits. It's handy.

Comment: `<c-w>o`> or `:windcmd o` is executing the window command "only". See `:h ctrl-w_o` for more.